# Shape with GaussianBlur SVG filter is exported as base64 <image>

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, appearance

I'm using Illustrator's default gaussian blur SVG filter:

```html
<filter  id="AI_GaussianBlur_4">
    <feGaussianBlur  stdDeviation="4"></feGaussianBlur>
</filter>
```

Shape appearance:

[image: appearance]

However, the exported SVG contains a base64 encoded image and not a shape with filters:

```html
...
    <g class="cls-3184">
      <image width="316" height="200" transform="translate(1760.45 695.76) scale(0.24)" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,XXXXXXXXXXXXX...."/>
    </g>
...
```

I manage to "manually" apply the filter by editing the svg and not applying the filter in Illustrator. I don't see why the program is ignoring it. Any advice?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate this problem. Do you have any other effect applied perhaps to a group that the object is in?

Comment: I do not. Perhaps I'm not exporting the SVG correctly. Do you use export or save as?

Comment: For me, it seems to work just fine, using either export as or save as.